# Sorting 2D Arraylist of Object

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist, localdate

I have 2D Arralist of Object and i want to sort it upon first column which contains LocalDate

i used this code to sort it

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");
    formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US );

ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> cusKashf = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

cusKashf.addAll(new ReadBillDeateals().readSell(textField_4.getText()));
Collections.sort(cusKashf , new Comparator<ArrayList<Object>>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(ArrayList<Object> entry1, ArrayList<Object> entry2) {
             return ((LocalDate.parse(entry1.get(0).toString(), formatter)).compareTo((LocalDate.parse(entry2.get(0).toString(), formatter))));
            }
        });
```

the problem is this code make an exception, i wonder where's the mistake in me code

this is the exception report

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at reports.Kashf$7$1.compare(Kashf.java:327)
    at reports.Kashf$7$1.compare(Kashf.java:1)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at reports.Kashf$7.actionPerformed(Kashf.java:324)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable example of your problem. The error says you are asking for item 2 of an empty list, but your code doesn't appear to do that. Your code appears to be asking for item 0 of a list (which could be empty).

Comment: The exception is clear: a list is empty. Make sure that involved lists are not empty

Comment: Yes that's right, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cusKashf List check if the sublist is not empty.

```
@Override
  public int compare(ArrayList<Object> entry1, ArrayList<Object> entry2) {
     if(Objects.isNull(entry1) || entry1.isEmpty())  return -1;
     if(Objects.isNull(entry2) || entry2.isEmpty())  return -1;

     return ((LocalDate.parse(entry1.get(0).toString(), formatter)).compareTo((LocalDate.parse(entry2.get(0).toString(), formatter))));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the lists you are trying to compare are empty, try surrounding by a try and catch or check if a list is empty before getting item 0.